# GraphQL Schema for a Social Network

Tags: json, api, server, graphql

I am learning about GraphQL so I decided to make a schema for some sort of social network. Please let me know if there are any best practices I should follow based on my schema below.

```
  scalar DateTime

  type Query {
      # user
      currentUser: User # use request "Authorization" header to get credentials
      getUser(uid: String!): User

      # friends
      getFriendRequest(requestId: Int!): FriendRequest
  }

  type Mutation {
      initializeNewUser: User!
      editCurrentUser(input: EditUserInput): User! 

      # friends
      sendFriendRequest(toUid: String!): FriendRequest
      # from this mutation, can accept or reject friend requests. 
      # server should handle adding of new friend on input.status == RequestStatus.accept
      updateFriendRequest(input: UpdateFriendRequestInput!): FriendRequest!

      # unfriend uid, and return updated list of friends
      unfriend(uid: String!): [Friend!]!
  }


  input UpdateFriendRequestInput {
      requestId: Int!
      status: RequestStatus!
  }


  input EditUserInput {
      displayName: String
      profilePic: String
  }


  type User {
      uid: String!
      profilePic: String
      displayName: String
      createdOn: DateTime!
      isOnline: Boolean
      friends: [Friend!]!
      friendRequests: [FriendRequest!]!
  }


  type Friend {
      user: User!
      friendsSince: DateTime!
      mutualFriends: [Friend!]!
  }


  type FriendRequest {
      requestId: Int!
      requestingUser: User!
      receivingUser: User!
      status: RequestStatus
      requestedAt: DateTime!
  }


  enum RequestStatus {
      pending
      accepted
      rejected
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! I've created the tag for you, since this is a relatively new technology we didn't have a tag for. I have refrained from unilaterally deciding whether reviewing a GraphQL schema definition is on-topic or not though - I'll cook up a [meta] post for the community to discuss and debate (IMO it's not very different than reviewing a plain SQL schema definition script, which *is* on-topic here albeit with an overlap with [dba.se]). In the meantime have an upvote, so that when the meta discussion is up you have enough rep to chime in as well.

Comment: Meta discussion about the tag: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9414/23788

Comment: As the meta discussion is currently making a rather solid case for GraphQL *schema* to be off-topic if presented without any code to consume it, I'll be putting this question on hold so that it can be freely edited without interference from potential answers.